# Add numbers and strings in python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, file-handling, filehandle

This may seem like a duplicate but the other ones don't apply. So I am trying to make a piggy bank but I cannot figure out how to add a new line while I am using numbers. Right now I am using strings because it is the only way to add a new line. However, when I add the two numbers, it adds them like string. For example, if you entered 5.93 twice. It would print "5.935.93". So, I have to convert it to a string but then I won't be able to add a new line. Here is my code:

```
def piggybank():
    file = open('piggybank.txt','r+')
    money = input('How much money are you adding?')
    file.write(money + '\n')
    for line in file:
        money += line
    print("You now have:\n", money)
    file.close()
```

In the third line I could make money a float but then in the fourth line I wouldn't be able to add a new line. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3):

You could keep `money` as an `Integer`, but when writing, use `%s`. Also, if you want to write to a file, you need to make a new variable set to `open('piggybank.txt', 'wb')` to write to the file.:

```
def piggybank():
    filew = open('piggybank.txt','wb')
    file = open('piggybank.txt','rb')
    money = input('How much money are you adding?')
    filew.write('%s\n' % money)
    for line in file:
        money += line
    print("You now have:\n%s" % money)
    filew.close()
    file.close()
```

Comment: I would add that the preferred string substituion is now `string.format()`, but maybe an even simpler method would be `print(money, file=file)`

Comment: I changed it to r+ and it still doesn't work. It doesn't add the money but it just prints the amounts multiple times.

Comment: Look, if you want to read a file, don't write to it! Use 'wb' instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
def piggybank():
    file = open('piggybank.txt','rb')
    money = input('How much money are you adding?')
    file.write(str(money) + "\n")
    for line in file:
        money += float(line.strip())
    print("You now have:\n" + str(money))
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to floats when your doing the math.

```
float(money) += float(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Addtion could be done between numeric objects.You need to notice that `input()` will give you a `str`(string) type object. And you need to convert `str` to `float` using `float()`.
- By trail and error,I've found following solition.Refernece doc links are [strip() doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), [open() doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open).

  ```
  def piggybank():
  file = open('piggybank.txt','a') #open file for appending to the end of it.
  money = input('How much money are you adding? ')
  file.write(money + '\n') # Write strings to text file.
  file.close()
  file = open('piggybank.txt','r')
  sum = float(0) # initialize sum with zero value.
  for line in file:
      sum += float(line.strip('\n')) # srtip '\n' and convert line from str to float.
  print("You now have: %s" % sum)
  file.close()
  ```